# Running pdflatex does not update file in Adobe Reader

Tags: pdftex, pdf, viewers, adobe

I am using Adobe Reader 9 to display PDF files in Ubuntu. When I run the `pdflatex` command, the file itself is updated as usual. But if the file is currently open in Adobe Reader, then the displayed file is not updated, and the result is that I have to close Adobe Reader and reopen the file. As you can imagine, this becomes annoying pretty fast.

How can I make it so that the displayed file is automatically updated?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with LaTeX...

Comment: Is very simple, use `evince` instead of Adobe Reader for view the pdf file. The most of times if I have open Reader, the following compilation attempt clashes because Reader is open. It's annoying, I know.

Comment: As @Aradnix mentions, use evince. This also have the benefit that it supports synctex, Adobe reader doesn't. AFAIR AR can ben reloaded manually using control-R

Comment: @HarishKumar: That's true fpr Windows, but not for Linux.

Comment: Use `evince` or `Okular`, both better for viewing PDF. What is the reasoning to use *the* Adobe Reader?

Comment: Adobe Reader for Linux has reached its End-Of-Life - there will be no more updates or security fixes. Use a different pdf viewer.